# Redis - Iterate through bitmap to get set bits

Tags: javascript, redis

I'm trying to iterate through a Redis bitmap and get the offset of all set bits.

I tried several methods but all of them have failed, here is a snipped I got from Redis Essentials book by Maxwell. I went through the code several times, still unable to figure out whats going wrong.

```
var bitmap = 'test';
redisClient.get(bitmap, function(err, bitmapValue){
    var userIds = [];

    var data = bitmapValue.toJSON().data;
    data.forEach(function(byte, byteIndex){
        for(var bitIndex = 7; bitIndex >= 0; bitIndex--) {
            var visited = byte >> bitIndex & 1;
        }
        if(visited === 1) {
            var userId = byteIndex * 8 + (7 - bitIndex);
            userIds.push(userId);
        }
    })

    console.log(userIds);
});
```

Most of the time I get empty result, usually when the bitmap is small. When I try large bitmaps I get array full of multiples of 8. A sample result I got is shown below, which is incorrect, the bitcount of that bitmap is 690, while I got only 91.

```
[8,
16,
32,
144,
176,
256,
320,
440,
456,
520,
584,
592,
624,
640,
648,
680,
696,
704,
712,
720,
752,
760,
848,
1056,
1088,
1104,
1112,
1120,
1136,
1144,
1160,
1168,
1224,
1248,
1264,
1280,
1312,
1328,
1424,
1480,
1496,
1544,
1600,
1680,
1792,
1824,
1840,
1904,
1976,
2080,
2112,
2144,
2224,
2240,
2296,
2392,
2400,
2504,
2512,
2584,
2616,
2712,
2856,
2880,
2912,
2976,
3048,
3288,
3328,
3352,
3360,
3368,
3376,
3432,
3440,
3496,
3600,
3616,
3624,
3632,
3704,
3752,
3776,
3832,
3880,
3936,
4056,
4264,
4296,
4352,
4376]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the bitmap you've stored under the key `test`, so testing is difficult. However, reading the code it looks like the if statement is placed wrongly - it should be:

```
var bitmap = 'test';
redisClient.get(bitmap, function(err, bitmapValue){
    var userIds = [];

    var data = bitmapValue.toJSON().data;
    data.forEach(function(byte, byteIndex){
        for(var bitIndex = 7; bitIndex >= 0; bitIndex--) {
            var visited = byte >> bitIndex & 1;
            if(visited === 1) {
                var userId = byteIndex * 8 + (7 - bitIndex);
                userIds.push(userId);
            }
        }
    })

    console.log(userIds);
});
```

Comment: It worked :), I guess I was not looking properly, Cheers!